# how to search with keyword in many tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have three tables  in my database book,author,publishing  ... i want the user can to search whithin the three tables if he write any word related . the same word  if not found in the book table it will search in the another table and so on...i do it but some thing wrong and i want it in one mysql sentence..anyone help me please

```
function getsomeword($keyword) {
    $result1 = $this->db->query("SELECT bo_id,bo_name,bo_state,bo_about FROM d_book where (bo_name like '%$keyword%' or bo_about like '%$keyword%') and bo_state = '1'");
    $result1 = $result1->num_rows();
    $result2 = $this->db->query("SELECT au_id,au_name,au_state,au_info FROM d_author where (au_name like '%$keyword%' or au_info like '%$keyword%') and au_state = '1'");
    $result2 = $result2->num_rows();
    $result3 = $this->db->query("SELECT pub_id,pub_name,pub_state,pub_info FROM d_publishing where (pub_name like '%$keyword%' or pub_info like '%$keyword%') and pub_state = '1'");
    $result3 = $result3->num_rows();
    return $result1 + $result2 + $result3;

}
```

Comment: You can use UNION (SQL) to solve this problem.

Comment: Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

Comment: Okay, you can also use Sphinx search engine to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the UNION keyword :

```
SELECT ...
UNION [ALL | DISTINCT] SELECT ...
[UNION [ALL | DISTINCT] SELECT ...]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Do NOT forget to sanitize your inputs, seems like you're putting the `$keyword` value in your query without escaping/sanitizing it before. You should look into `PDO::prepare` to prevent SQL injection (http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

Comment: Yes, and it seems like the perfect fit with the example queries.